# Select script for selecting two columns in a table

Tags: sql, postgresql, null, union

I need help writing a Select script which selects data from two columns based on a condition.
Say, I have a table:

```
Table: X 
Columns: ID, Type , and Old_type
```

Column `Old_type` has nulls or historic type values and column `Type` has either type values or the overwritten values of `Old_type`:

```
Id     Type          Old_type
 1     ABC           NULL
 2     ZYZ           BCD
```

I need to write a script which selects data from column `Type` if `Old_type` column is null else it should select the values of `Type` column in separate row and `Old_type` in separate row. Or simply I need the following output:

```
Output
Id   Type
1    ABC
2    ZYX
2    BCD
```

Comment: `Id = 3` is a typo in the result I assume? Also, this may be more appropriate for SO, since we prefer to deal with advanced SQL questions on dba.SE.

Comment: I usually get confused where to post SQL queries when I post in SO some people advised me to post here saying it's DB related. How do you classify whether a query is advanced or not?

Comment: It's not always clear. This seems like a basic issue though. Maybe, you can draw the line there: If you are experience with SQL and still puzzled by a problem, come here. If you are a beginner, you should generally go to SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`UNION ALL`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-union.html) does the trick:

```
SELECT id, type FROM x
UNION  ALL
SELECT id, old_type FROM x WHERE old_type IS NOT NULL
ORDER  BY id;
```